# Trying to pass returned values independently from each other into a another methods attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am going to make this simple, because I am still not quite that comfortable with Python object-oriented programming.

```
ip = raw_input("Device ip: ")

# Ask for connection credentials

def get_credentials():
    username = raw_input("Username: ")
    password = None
    while not password:
        password = getpass()
        password_verify = getpass('Retype your password: ')
        if password != password_verify:
            print ('Passwords do not match. Try again.')
            password = None
        return username, password


waiting_displaying = "."

connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(ip, get_credentials.username, get_credentials.password, device_type='cisco_ios' )
```

Based on the code listed above

> I am trying to get the value in username and password to be passed from their local variables to the attributes section of the `ConnectHandler` method in the `netmiko` module.

I have heard online that you can pass the returned values but since I'm guessing they are stored as a tuple or a dictionary key, it seems a little difficult to do so and I am not quite sure how to go about doing it.

**For the record:**

- `getpass` was imported from a module named `getpass`.
- `ConnectHandler` was imported from a module named `netmiko`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [collections.namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). It is simple and fast way to create tuple-like object that have fields accessible by attribute lookup.

```
Credentials = collections.namedtuple('Credentials', ['username', 'password'], verbose=True)
def get_credentials():
     ...
     return Credentials(username, password)

cc = get_credentials()
connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(ip,cc.username,   cc.password, device_type='cisco_ios' )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, would you mind elaborating why you chose this method of going about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which hold the data:

```
class Credentials:
    def __init__(self,username='',password=''):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
    def get_credentials(self):
        # update self.username and self.password
        self.username = ...
        self.password = ...

cc = Credentials()
cc.get_credentials()
connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(ip, cc.username, cc.password, device_type='cisco_ios' )
```